# ng build returns fatal out of memory exception in Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, docker

I'm trying to build the frontend of a web application in a Node.js Docker container. As I'm on a Windows PC, I'm very limited in my base Images. I chose [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/node-windows/), as it's the only one on DockerHub with a decent number of downloads. As the application is meant to run in Azure, I'm also limited to Windowsservercore 2016. When I run the following Dockerfile, I get the error message below (on my host system the build runs fine btw):

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:10.15.3-windowsservercore-2016
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.4

COPY . ./

RUN ng build
```

---

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory on the background thread
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000E37E3FA6D0
```

I tried increasing the memory available to the build process with *--max_old_space* up to 16GB (the entire RAM of my laptop) but that didn't help. I also contacted the author of the base image to find out if that's the issue but as this doesn't seem to be reproducable with a smaller example application, that wasn't very fruitful either. I'm working on this issue for a week now and I'm seriously out of ideas what could be the reason. So I hope to get a new impulse from here. At least a dircetion I could investigate in.

What I also tried was getting Node.js and Angular installed on a Windowsservercore base image. If someone has an idea how to do that, it could be the solution.

EDIT: I noticed that the error message is the **only** output I get from the build process, it doesn't even get to try building the modules. Maybe that means something...

Comment: Well if you want something minimal, why not [`alpine-node`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/) ? As you can see, it's widely used, and alpine is the best choice for lightweighted containers.

Comment: Isn't Alpine a Linux Distribution or somehting only availible on Linux? I'm a big noob when it comes to Linux so sorry if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Show me the budgets json array inside angular.json file

Comment: That's the purpose of Docker, being able to run containers regardless of the OS you're on. You can totally run a Linux container on Windows ! I thought your statement "I'm very limited in my base Images" was about the support of Docker for Windows, but once it's installed, all the containers are available to you !

Comment: @trichetriche Quote from the [Docker Classroom](https://training.play-with-docker.com/beginner-linux/):
However, Linux containers require the Docker host to be running a Linux kernel. For example, Linux containers cannot run directly on Windows Docker hosts. The same is true of Windows containers - they need to run on a Docker host with a Windows kernel.

Comment: @dota2pro There is no budgets arry in the angular.json file

Comment: @TigersEye120 ... read this then https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-size-budgets

Comment: @TigersEye120 I have never had any issues running an ubuntu or alpine container on my €300 windows computer with docker tools ... But maybe this has changed !

Comment: @dota2pro I experiemented a bit with the budgets. I gave my entire app 1GB and baseline and set a warning at 50%, but nothing changed.

Comment: "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1GB",
                  "maximumError": "1GB"
                } like this ?

Comment: Jep, also tried "budgets": [ {
      "type": "all",
      "baseline": "1024mb",
      "warning": "50%"
     }
    ], both made no difference.

Comment: I made some new discoveries related to Dockers memory usage, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438367/vmmem-crashes-at-1gb-memory-usage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. Although the official Docker documentation states, that Docker has unlimited access to resources, it seems that you need to use the -m option when your build process exceeds a certain amount of memory.

**Edit:** This question seems to be getting some views so maybe I should clarify this answer a bit. The root of the problem seems to be that under Windows, Docker runs inside a Hyper-V VM. So when the documentation talks about "unlimited access to resources", it doesn't mean your PC's resources, but instead the resources of that VM.