# Vmmem crashes at 1GB memory usage

Tags: angular, windows, docker

I'm currently investigating an OOM exception when using Angular with Docker described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294142/ng-build-returns-fatal-out-of-memory-exception-in-docker) question. I'm opening this one for my newest discovery as this might be a more general issue.

When my Angular app gets build in the Docker container, the task *Vmmem*, which apperently handles all of Windows' VM memory usage, starts taking up a lot of my RAM (obviously). But when it reaches between 900MB and 1000MB, it just shuts down instantly.

At this point, my computer is at ~70% RAM capacity, so I still have a couple GB left, which should be availible to Docker, as there are no resource limitaions by default. I also used the *Budgets* mechanic in Angular to allow the build process to use a lot more RAM then that, yet the VM still seems to crash at around 1GB of RAM usage.

Comment: Have you tried the `--max_old_space-size` fix mentioned in the question you link to?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. See the answer on my original question linked above if you're interested, as I'm apparently not allowed to post the same answer twice.